# create a js file with variables of an dataobject - Sivlerstripe 3.1

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I've written a ModelAdmin to manage the Imageslider of my Website.
One Dataobject which is managed by the ModelAdmin is "SliderSettings". There you can set the slider behavior.

The variables set there, should be saved into a js file and included to the template.
I know you can create a inline js with your variables if you use a controller. But this won't work with Dataobjects and creates inline js, is there a way to do this with my Dataobject and create a file not a inline js?

Here's my Code http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525d094569329

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise **against** writing a file, instead I would recommend using `Requirements::customScript()`

Yes, that would be useless if you put it somewhere where it does not get called (in the DataObject)
So lets put it somewhere it makes sense, eg the Page_Controller->init(),
of course then we need to get the SliderSettings Object, this can be done with SliderSettings::get()->First(), this gives you the first SliderSettings Object in the Database, if you want to get a specifc one, you can also get it by ID: SliderSettings::get()->byID(42)

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $sliderSettings = SliderSettings::get()->First();
        if ($sliderSettings) {
            $sliderSettings = Convert::array2json(array(
                'SliderEffect'   => $sliderSettings->SliderEffect,
                'SliderCaptions' => $sliderSettings->SliderCaptions,
                'SliderRandom'   => $sliderSettings->SliderRandom,
                'SliderTicker'   => $sliderSettings->SliderTicker,
                'SliderPager'    => $sliderSettings->SliderPager,
                'SliderControls' => $sliderSettings->SliderControls,
                'SliderStart'    => $sliderSettings->SliderStart,
                'SliderAdaptive' => $sliderSettings->SliderAdaptive,
                'SliderSpeed'    => $sliderSettings->SliderSpeed,
                'SliderPause'    => $sliderSettings->SliderPause,
            ));
            Requirements::customScript("var sliderSettings = $sliderSettings;");
            // Requirements::customScript will put it at the bottom of the HTML, if you need it above the other JS files, you can put it into the header with the following workaround/hack: (if you use this, remove the Requirements::customScript line)
            // Requirements::insertHeadTags("<script type='text/javascript'>var sliderSettings = $sliderSettings;</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

that's it, now you should have a variable named `sliderSettings` availiable in javascript.
this variable is an object, so you can access it like this: `sliderSettings.SliderEffect` or `sliderSettings['SliderEffect']`
**NOTE**: the variable will be AFTER your JS files, so it will not be availiable directly in the code, but you can access it inside of `$(document).ready(function() {})`.

Comment: hi zauberfisch, that sounds great, i used your code 1 to 1 and put this into my js file http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525d3cd158899. this file is loaded before the inline script with the variable at the bottom of the html document http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525d3d2552d4f. But it doesn't work. the variables weren't deliverd :/

Comment: I edited the code example (see the 2 comment lines at the bottom below the Requirements::customScript() part), this should do the trick for you

Comment: still doesn't work :/ the wright variables are in the template but not in the js file. I'm combining my js files and include them with requirements.

Comment: still they should be avaliable. is this http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525d3cd158899 your full javascript code? are you getting any error message? try `console.log(sliderSettings);` and see what it outputs

Comment: that's one of my files. the file for everything which should be loaded when the document is ready. here's a screenshot, perhaps that helps? http://img1.picload.org/image/ocdlicr/unbenannt-1.jpg

Comment: well, from the console.log() it would see that it is working, but I do see a problem, "false" and "true" is in quotes, which makes them string rather than boolean.

Comment: the reason that is is because you save it as string in the database. you now have 2 options: either convert them to boolean by hand like so: http://paste2.org/2nBW7HZU or you can change the DB values of the dataobject to be actual booleans, ints, ...

Comment: You're genius ;) But is it also possible to write it into an file? So that i can combine it with all the other js files?

Comment: yes it is possible, in fact pretty easy. there is the php method `file_put_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php, you can do: `file_put_contents('folder/names/file.js', "var sliderSettings = $sliderSettings;")` but I **strongly advise against it**, especially **against** using it with combined files, that is just a **very bad idea**. you will have to rewrite the combined file everytime, the combined file is no longer cache able or worse, it will be cached and it does not update the new configs

Comment: okay than i wan't do it. but i put the code back to end of the side. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

could you use something like that?

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $sliderSettings = DataObject::get_by_id('SliderSettings ', $this->ID);
    if ( $sliderSettings )
    {
        $sliderSettings = Convert::raw2json( $sliderSettings->toMap() );
        Requirements::customScript(<<<JS
          var sliderSettings = $sliderSettings;
        JS
        );
    }
}
```

this would serialize the current `SliderSettings` DataObject and make it accessible to Javascript via a `sliderSettings` object in the global scope via a custom script tag.

Your option with `javascriptTemplate` can probably work but without seeing the JS file, it's hard to debug.

**EDIT**

Considering it is hard to control the order of requirements, like @Zauberfisch mentioned. A solution can be to have a custom function in your Controller like so:

```
public function SliderSettings()
{
    $sliderSettings = DataObject::get_by_id('SliderSettings ', $this->ID);
    if ( $sliderSettings )
    {
        return Convert::raw2json( $sliderSettings->toMap() );
    }
    else{
        return '{}';
    }
}
```

This would make a `$SliderSettings` variable available in your template which you can use anywhere. For example to have the JSON included in the HEAD (maybe not the best...) or just before any other scripts like so `<script>var sliderSetting = $SliderSettings;</script>`

Comment: thx, where should i put this code? PageController? what i forget to ask, is it possible to have an controller class in an dataobject? Here's the js file http://sspaste.com/paste/show/525d1fcc9d8dd

Comment: colymba's answer is on the right track, but I posted an more detailed and more specific answer.

Comment: cSGermany, to your question of PageController in DataObject. Well the short answer is no. The long answer is to long for a comment, just let me say that your question does not make much sense, and that, what ever you are trying to do, it most likely is possible, you probably just have a wrong approach. Open a new question with your code and a description of what you want to do, I am sure it's easier than you think.

Comment: @cSGermany that would be your Controller's init function. Also edited the answer with a more flexible solution...